# JOIN entre 4 tablas con DJANGO

Tags: django, postgresql, join

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta entre varias tablas, las cuales he cargado desde una base de datos ya existente. Al momento de cargar los models en django aparecen de la siguiente manera:

```
class T0001Personas(models.Model):
  c0001codpersona = models.CharField(primary_key=True, db_comment='Codigo de Persona calculado')
  i0001subtippers = models.ForeignKey('T0003Subtippersona', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='i0001subtippers', db_comment='Sub Tipo de Persona (Gobierno, Entidad Religiosa,etc)')
  b0001cliente = models.BooleanField(db_comment='Indica si es cliente o no')
  b0001proveedor = models.BooleanField(db_comment='Indica si es proveedor o no')
  i0001idpais = models.ForeignKey('T0006Paises', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='i0001idpais', db_comment='Pais de origen')
  c0001nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_comment='Nombre completo')
  c0001idlugar = models.ForeignKey('T0008Lugares', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='c0001idlugar', db_comment='Codigo de lugar')
  c0001codvia = models.ForeignKey('T0012Vias', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='c0001codvia', db_comment='Codigo de Via')
  c0001numero = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, db_comment='Numero Municipal')
  c0001dpto = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True, db_comment='Numero de departamento')
  c0001piso = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, db_comment='Numero de piso')
  c0001block = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, db_comment='Numero de Block')
  c0001manzana = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, db_comment='Manzana')
  c0001lote = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, db_comment='Lote')
  c0001usuario = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True, db_comment='Usuario que Registra')
  d0001fecha = models.DateTimeField(db_comment='Fecha de Registro')
  b0001estado = models.BooleanField(db_comment='Estado')

  class Meta:
      managed = False
      db_table = 't0001Personas'

class T0002Tipopersona(models.Model):
  i0002idtipopersona = models.SmallAutoField(primary_key=True)
  c0002nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  c0002usuario = models.CharField(max_length=35, db_comment='Usuario del sistema')
  d0002fecha = models.DateTimeField(db_comment='Fecha de Registro')
  b0002estado = models.BooleanField(db_comment='Estado')

  class Meta:
      managed = False
      db_table = 't0002TipoPersona'

class T0012Vias(models.Model):
  c0012codvia = models.CharField(primary_key=True, db_comment='Codigo de Via Calculado')
  c0012nombre = models.CharField(max_length=70)
  i0012idtipovia = models.SmallIntegerField()
  c0012usuario = models.CharField(max_length=35, db_comment='Usuario del sistema')
  d0012fecha = models.DateTimeField(db_comment='Fecha de Registro')
  b0012estado = models.BooleanField(db_comment='Estado')

  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 't0012Vias'
```

La defición en los views.py lo nombré clientes, dado que al hacer la consulta, aplicaré un .filter(b0001cliente=True) a la tabla personas y quedaría así:

```
def clientes(request):
  #Para visualizar la consulta en consola 
print(T0001Personas.objects.all().select_related('c0001codvia').filter(b0001cliente=True).query)

listClientes = T0001Personas.objects.all().select_related('c0001codvia').filter(b0001cliente=True)
for clientes in listClientes:
    print(clientes.c0001nombre, clientes.c0001numero, clientes.T0012Vias.c0012nombre, clientes.c0001idlugar)

datos = { 'clientes': listClientes }
return render(request, 'clientes.html', datos)
```

El resultado en consola no arroja los datos de la T0012Vias, solo muestra los datos de la T0001Personas, y deseo tener los datos de la columna id, c0001nombre, c0001idlugar, T0012Vias.c0012nombre, para luego pasarlos a un 'template' y poderlos visualizar en un html.